# Host VMs on Ubuntu Server and access them remotely?

Tags: server, virtualization, remote-access

Is it possible to host virtual machines on a workstation running Ubuntu Server 16.04 (no GUI) and log into them remotely from a Windows PC?

Comment: You are asking a yes-or-no question. The answer is 'yes'. However, there are *many* ways to remotely access applications and/or data. (ssh, LTSP, remote-destop, HTML, etc) We can provide you better advice or instruction if you explain your actual dilemma a bit more clearly.

Comment: Thanks, please see comment on Panther's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely and you have multiple options for doing so.

Personally I use Proxmox, it is Debian based, but has a great web interface.

https://www.proxmox.com/en/

It depends a bit on which virtualization you choose, personally I use KVM. You can manage your KVM machines from windows

See https://serverfault.com/questions/340949/is-there-a-way-to-run-virt-manager-on-windows

For example see http://www.ubuntuboss.com/ubuntu-server-16-04-as-a-hypervisor-using-kvm-and-kimchi-for-vm-management/

A complete list of options is here - https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Management_Tools

Docker is very popular and has web interfaces as well

https://blog.ouseful.info/2015/08/10/seven-graphical-interfaces-to-docker/

There are other options from virtualbox to Xen to Vmware.

So in a way, your question is too broad and I would suggest you ask a more specific question if you have a problem once you have done some research into  your options.

- What virtualization technology ? KVM ? Docker ? Other ?
- What interface ? ssh ? web ? VNC ? Spice ? Command line ?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. I'm setting up a SOHO network. I have a few older Windows workstations with limited memory and slower CPUs. I'd like to configure a new workstation with Ubuntu Server, define virtual workstations on the server, and remote desktop from the Windows workstations into the virtual machines, essentially making use of the Windows workstations as thin clients to view the graphical desktops of the VMs running on the server. I've used VMWare and Hyper-V in the past to Host VMs on a Windows workstation, but I've never set up virtualization on a server.

Comment: You still have tons of options. KVM + spice . It is very fast protocol. Spice is a VNC server as a part of KVM. You then download and install the spice clients to your windows brethren and done. Some people like vmware. Docker has lower overhead ....... Decisions decisions =)